# How to directly set response body to a file stream in ASP.NET Core middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

Sample code below to write a file stream to `Response.Body` in an ASP.NET Core middleware doesn't work (emits empty response):

```cs
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    using (var fs = new FileStream("/valid-path-to-file-on-server.txt", FileMode.Open)
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        context.Response.Body = sr.BaseStream;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with this approach of directly setting the `context.Response.Body`?

Note: any next middleware in the pipeline is skipped for no further processing.

**Update** (another example): a simple `MemoryStream` assignment doesn't work either (empty response):

```cs
context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. No. You can never do that directly.

   Note that `context.Response.Body` is a reference to an object ([`HttpResponseStream`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/9098a47dbfede8c549633090fe931687a4e9ee8d/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpResponseStream.cs#L13)) that is **[initialized before](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3ecdc403189a28e2f36723663f50e58c4637e3aa/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs#L609-L611) it becomes available in `HttpContext`**. It is assumed that all bytes are written into this original Stream. If you change the `Body` to reference (*point to*) a new stream object by `context.Response.Body = a_new_Stream`, the original `Stream` is not changed at all.

   Also, if you look into the source code of `ASP.NET Core`, you'll find the Team always **copy** the wrapper stream to the original body stream at the end rather than with a simple replacement(unless they're unit-testing with a mocked stream). For example, the [SPA Prerendering middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/8c02467b4a218df3b1b0a69bceb50f5b64f482b1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L129) source code:

   ```cs
       finally
       {
           context.Response.Body = originalResponseStream;
           ...
   ```

   And the [`ResponseCachingMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d7bfbb5824b5f8876bcd4afaa29a611efc7aa1c9/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingMiddleware.cs#L443) source code:

   ```cs
       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
       {
           ...
           finally
           {
               UnshimResponseStream(context);
           }
           ...
       }

       internal static void UnshimResponseStream(ResponseCachingContext context)
       {
           // Unshim response stream
           context.HttpContext.Response.Body = context.OriginalResponseStream;

           // Remove IResponseCachingFeature
           RemoveResponseCachingFeature(context.HttpContext);
       }
   ```
2. As a walkaround, you can *copy* the bytes to the raw stream as below:

   ```cs
   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
       context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       using (var fs = new FileStream("valid-path-to-file-on-server.txt", FileMode.Open))
       {
           await fs.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
       }
   }
   ```

   Or if you like to *hijack* the raw `HttpResponseStream` with your own stream wrapper:

   ```cs
       var originalBody = HttpContext.Response.Body;
       var ms = new MemoryStream();
       HttpContext.Response.Body = ms;
       try
       {
           await next();
           HttpContext.Response.Body = originalBody;
           ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           await ms.CopyToAsync(HttpContext.Response.Body);
       }
       finally
       {
           response.Body = originalBody;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. For file content response, I think `httpContext.Response.SendFileAsync` will work as well, eliminating the need for `FileStream` altogether.

Comment: @Nick Yes, absolutely. The above `CopyToAsync` is just a way that illustrates how to deal with a plain `Stream`. If you're dealing with a File, feel free to use an easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statements in the question causes your stream and stream reader to be rather ephemeral, so they will both be disposed. The extra reference to the steam in "body" wont prevent the dispose.

The framework disposes of the stream after sending the response. (The medium is the message).

Answer (score 0):

In net 6 I found I was getting console errors when I tried to do this e.g.:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Response Content-Length mismatch: too many bytes written (25247 of 8863).`

The solution was to remove the relevant header:

```cs
context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");
await context.Response.SendFileAsync(filename);
```